# Signal SIGABRT, runtime/cgo: could not obtain pthread_keys when running on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, runtime-error, sigabrt, cgo

I am trying to get my app running on simulator, but am getting this error on launch: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHJ7c.png)

What does this mean, and how can I determine what code is causing the error? Thanks!
Here's the back trace:

```
* thread #3, stop reason = signal SIGABRT
  * frame #0: 0x0000000107d5cb66 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x0000000107d96080 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 333
    frame #2: 0x00000001012b7405 libclang_rt.tsan_iossim_dynamic.dylib`wrap_pthread_kill + 325
    frame #3: 0x0000000107b09c45 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 127
    frame #4: 0x00000001012b669c libclang_rt.tsan_iossim_dynamic.dylib`wrap_abort + 108
    frame #5: 0x00000001008d5c0f GiFmojo`inittls + 431
    frame #6: 0x00000001008d5a32 GiFmojo`runtime.etext + 98
    frame #7: 0x00000001006fe19c GiFmojo`runtime.rt0_go + 140
    frame #8: 0x0000000107d93661 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 340
    frame #9: 0x0000000107d9350d libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 377
    frame #10: 0x0000000107d92bf9 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting the simulator, Xcode, cleaning the project, deleting Derived Data, and restarting your computer?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but unfortunately the crash persists

Comment: Other things you could try would be to change the simulator device, try running on an actual device, and reinstalling Xcode.